# Aggregation pipeline $graphLookup results a referenced value of other collection. I want to populate the value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here `aTrips` have Objects that has property `bills` which refer to other collection data. I want to populate that data.

How to populate bills?

```
  let aFleetOwnerTripData = await RegisteredVehicleModel.aggregate( 
   [ { $match:{clientId:req.user.clientId,"owner_group":{$exists:true}} },
     { $group:{_id:"$owner_group",aVehicle: {$push: "$vehicle_reg_no"},count : {$sum : 1}} }, 
     { $graphLookup: { 
       from: "tripv2", 
       startWith: "$aVehicle", 
       connectFromField: "aVehicle", 
       connectToField: "vehicle_no", 
       as: "aTrips", 
      restrictSearchWithMatch: {
       "clientId" : req.user.clientId, 
       "statuses":{ 
         $elemMatch:{ status:status, date:{ "$gte": startDate, "$lte": currentDate } } 
       } 
     } 
    } } ] 
);
```